# ¿Cómo evitar repetición de la materia seleccionada?

Tags: java

Buen día, como puedo hacer que no se repita la misma materia seleccionada, o también, para que se mueva a la siguiente opción al seleccionar

```
    for (int d = 0; d <= 7; d++) {
            do {
                materias[d] = (String) JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Materias a evaluar ", "Elige la materia " + (d + 1) + " a evaluar", JOptionPane.YES_OPTION, iconob, listaMaterias, listaMaterias[3]);
                if (materias != null) {

                    for (int e = 0; e <= 2; e++) {
                        
                        String n2;
                        esNumeroValido = false;
                        esRangoValido = false;
                        do {
                            n2 = (JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Introduce la calificacion del " + (e + 1) + " Unidad"));
                            esNumeroValido = validar.isNumeric(n2);
//                            calificaciones[d][e] = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Introduce la calificacion del " + (e + 1) + " Unidad"));

                            if (esNumeroValido) {
                                esRangoValido = validarRango(Integer.parseInt(n2), 6, 10);
                                if (esRangoValido) {
                                    calificaciones[d][e] = Integer.parseInt(n2);
                                    
                                } else {
                                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Ingresa una calificacion valida 6-10");
                                }
                                suma2 += calificaciones[d][e];
                                promedioP[d]= suma2/3;
                            } else {
                                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "ERROR, debes introducir un numero");
                            }

                        } while ((!esNumeroValido) || (!esRangoValido));
                        
                        
                    }
                        
                      
                        suma = promedioP[d];
                }

            } while (materias == null);

        }
```

El arreglo esta declarado en String, quiero hacer que no se vuelva a repetir la opción seleccionada.

Eso es lo que me pide mi profesor, pero se me ocurre hacer que cuando se elija una opción se mueva a la siguiente

Comment: Hola. Consideras que con lo que compartiste es suficiente para saber qué estás haciendo y poderte dar una respuesta adecuada?

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! de que opciones hablas? que no se repita lo seleccionado donde?

Comment: No, no lo es disculpen.

Comment: @Ramly Necesitas proporcionarnos un [mre], si no podemos copiar tu código y ejecutarlo, no podemos debugarlo ni probar cosas. Es **necesario** que el código que pasas COMPILE Y SE EJECUTE. No necesitamos *TODO* tu código, simplemente añade las declaraciones de variables que faltan, como por ejemplo el array de materias. Si me tengo que inventar partes de tu código es posible que no consiga reproducir tus mismos problemas. Proporciona siempre un [mre] cuando busques ayuda, por favor.

Comment: `listaMaterias` que valores tiene? que ejemplo de entrada esperas que se use? porque comparar solo dos materias?